# Linear Maps and Basis of Domain

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I don't understand the theorem from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:

Suppose $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,....,w_n \in W$. Then there exists a unique linear map $T: V \to W$ such that $Tv_j = w_j$ for $j = 1,...,n$

What is this trying to say? I don't understand.

In addition, I don't understand the proof of this by construction. How does this show it exists, and how does the uniqueness proof indeed show that it is unique?

Comment: I don't know what it's trying to say, but I see what it uses: a linear map from a vector space $V$ to another vector space is uniquely defined by the images of the vectors in a basis.

Comment: I agree with Bernard, see page 158, prop. 7.2.17 of my notes http://www.supermath.info/LinearNotes2015.pdf

Comment: So in other words, there will always exist a linear map with the described property between sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that once you know how $T$ acts on a basis, you know how it acts on ALL vectors $v\in V$. To see this, suppose we have defined $T$ on , $\left \{ v_{1}, v_{2},v_{3}\cdots v_{n}\right \}$, a basis for $V$:

$Tv_{1}=w_{1}, Tv_{2}=w_{2}, \cdots ,Tv_{n}=w_{n}$

We can express $v$ as a linear combnation of the basis vectors, by writing

$v=a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+a_{3}v_{3}\cdots a_{n}v_{n}$.

Now apply $T$:

$Tv=T(a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+a_{3}v_{3}\cdots a_{n}v_{n})$.

But $T$ is linear so we get

$Tv=a_{1}Tv_{1}+a_{2}Tv_{2}+a_{3}Tv_{3}\cdots a_{n}Tv_{n}$.

So the effect of $T$ on our arbitrary $v$ only depended on how we defined $T$ on the basis $\left \{ v_{1}, v_{2},v_{3}\cdots v_{n}\right \}$

Comment: But we can find other linear maps as well where Tv_i does not necessarily map to w_i

Comment: And also what does it mean that linear maps can be "made" to take on arbitrary values?